# OpenCV depth Map from Stereo Images with nonparallel epilines

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I found a tutorial about [getting a depth map from stereo images](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_calib3d/py_depthmap/py_depthmap.html) which contains this piece of code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

imgL = cv2.imread('tsukuba_l.png',0)
imgR = cv2.imread('tsukuba_r.png',0)

stereo = cv2.createStereoBM(numDisparities=16, blockSize=15)
disparity = stereo.compute(imgL,imgR)
plt.imshow(disparity,'gray')
plt.show()
```

Short question:

Do epipolar lines have to be parallel for this algorithm to work? I have two cameras which act as a stereo system but there is a small rotation and translation between them since I just put them on a table. So my epilines are by far not parallel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, epipolar lines need to be parallel for `createStereoBM` to work.

For that you need to estimate the extrinsic calibration between your two cameras (Rotation and translation). It works basically the same as mono camera calibration. There are a few stereo calibration tutorials out there but I haven't found a good python one just now. Take a look at [ROS camera calibration tool](http://wiki.ros.org/camera_calibration).

Next you need to rectify your camera images. This means you use the mapping you get from stereo calibration and warp your images so the epipolar lines are parallel. Take a look at the `stereoRectify` documentation by OpenCV: [here](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#stereorectify).

When you have called `initUndistortRectifyMap` with the calibration parameters as suggested in the documentation I linked, your images are warped so that the epipolar lines are parallel, now you should be able to use `createStereoBM` to create a disparity map.