# Calculate Depth Map in OpenCV Python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, vision

I want to calculate the depth map of a stereo system, not the disparity alone.

**Input:**
I am a little bit new to this part of OpenCV. I have two cameras, intrinsic and extrinsic parameters for both cameras, and rotation and translation between two cameras.

**Output:**
I want to use the current rotation, translation, and camera parameters to calculate the depth map. I do not want to re-calculate those parameters. However, I do not know the proper python OpenCV functions.

My two cameras have angels with respect to each other.

[image]

Comment: Did you tried the example provided in the documentation? https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/dd/d53/tutorial_py_depthmap.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calculate depth disparity map using opencv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58113312/calculate-depth-disparity-map-using-opencv)

Comment: @GonzaloOdiard Hi, about the first link: in the picture it assumed a simple stereo. The second camera is shifted to the right. My cameras are not like that, they have angels. Also, I saw no argument in it to give the function translation and rotation matrix between to cameras.

Comment: Maybe this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58321848/opencv-depth-map-from-stereo-images-with-nonparallel-epilines ?

Comment: @Farhad the "difficult" stereo setup with rotation and translation is typically transformed to the simple setup by "rectification" of the images. After computing the disparity you can translate it to depth with a sinple formula where the stereo baseline must be known. Afair it's mostly c/disparity where c is a constant factor.

Comment: @Micka thank you for your answer, It gave me some ideas.